# Reduce granularity to days, months, years in date-fns formatDistanceToNow

Tags: javascript, typescript, time, date-fns

im using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) library to calculate distance to an event in time.
For example:

```
formatDistanceToNow(nextEventDate, { addSuffix: true });
```

which will produce nice human friendly output: 'in about 1 month'. All well and good, however when a distance is less then one day the same method will produce messages such as: 'in 1 minute' or 'in 3 seconds' or 'in 2 hours'.

How can I reduce granularity such that if time frame is less than a day, then result will be 'today'? I would like to keep the output rounded to years, months, weeks, days but I don't want seconds, minutes, hours.

I tried different method within the library (formatDistance, formatDistanceStrict) and tried removing hours, minutes and seconds from date parameter, however with no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method would be to manually check for distances less than 24hrs:

```
import {formatDistanceToNow} from "date-fns"
function formatDistanceDay(date: Date): string {
    const oneDay = 1000 * 3600 * 24;
    const distance = Date.now() - date.getTime();
    if (distance < oneDay && distance > 0) {
        return "today";
    }
    return formatDistanceToNow(date, {addSuffix: true})
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwGbRAQxgEWAZxmgOwGMBTAFQgDkIB3AXziSghDgCIATDEgWiQJxsAsACgkAV2IxgEAo1QZseQqUxoAngAouMEgC44a3QEoDeKMAIBzRKLj24RWXjiySa9XAC8cAIwAGQLgAKjgAZgA2INCAJgAWAG47BycBeA5cfGISb0NuADoCWk1jOB44HRJ8qxIYMlASEqSRBzhgJDhtTJUcgB5XAncNOAAyEYru7LgAPjh-UoRk1vsoWvEoOTYYCC51NmbWuiW4VZh1uRQodCxJ0gpqGm1uABpENA4OAGVxJCRgAA8DDAoOISHRjKI6EA)